# Why use "interior-point" when optimizing with fmincon in MATLAB, is "active-set " as good?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

When using optimization solver fmincon in MATLAB, the default method is "interier point". Why is the "interier point" algorithm preferred over the "active set" algorithm. I am doing a project and been told to use "active set" and I am not sure I understand the difference. My optimization problem has a large number of variables in the objective function, and the constraints are linear or nonlinear inequalities.

Comment: Do you have read https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/constrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html ?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to ask the person who told you to use the active set algorithm the reason for that. Note: often active set solutions look nicer (e.g. 0 instead of 0.00001).